# application/problem+json and .net 6 minimal APIs?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I created a very basic project that just throws an exception, expecting to get an application/problem+json response, but instead I get an html page with error details.
I am guessing this is the "Developer exception page" that some posts I read talk about, but I had not added that to the startup.

complete code example:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => {
    throw new System.Exception("Hello, World!");
    return new string[] { };
});

app.Run();
```

I was not able to find anything pertinent googling this, which I presume is a result of this being very fresh.

Will the behaviour change if not running in visual studio?
Can I change it so I get the application/problem+json (also) while running in visual studio?

Comment: hm.. weird if i look at https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-2-comparing-webapplicationbuilder-to-the-generic-host/#asp-net-core-6-webapplicationbuilder- he has to explicitlly confire the development exception page. I can't see any mention of the exception development page in the default webapplication builder https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0621c1748eac08dd516edc950559ab7e8308f214/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L215 so i'm curious where its coming from.

Perhaps step into the framework with the debugger and see if this is configured somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The developer exception page is now on by default (in .NET 6) when running in the "Development" environment (i.e. `IWebHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment()` is true).

Typically when configuring exception handling in an ASP.NET Core application there will be separate paths taken for exception handling during development vs. production (or more strictly, non-development). The developer exception page (as the name suggests) is only intended for use in development, whereas the exception handler middleware (`app.UseExceptionHandler`) is intended for non-development scenarios.

To return problem details responses for exceptions, you'll need to configure both paths separately. The developer exception page has a plug-in model via the `IDeveloperPageExceptionFilter` interface that can be used to take control of how exceptions are rendered. [Here's an example](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MinimalApiPlayground/blob/main/src/MinimalApiPlayground/Properties/ProblemDetailsDeveloperPageExceptionFilter.cs) of a filter that renders the exception as problem details when the client indicates it supports JSON:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;

/// <summary>
/// Formats <see cref="DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware"/> exceptions as JSON Problem Details if the client indicates it accepts JSON.
/// </summary>
public class ProblemDetailsDeveloperPageExceptionFilter : IDeveloperPageExceptionFilter
{
    private static readonly object ErrorContextItemsKey = new object();
    private static readonly MediaTypeHeaderValue _jsonMediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    private static readonly RequestDelegate _respondWithProblemDetails = RequestDelegateFactory.Create((HttpContext context) =>
    {
        if (context.Items.TryGetValue(ErrorContextItemsKey, out var errorContextItem) && errorContextItem is ErrorContext errorContext)
        {
            return new ErrorProblemDetailsResult(errorContext.Exception);
        }

        return null;
    }).RequestDelegate;

    public async Task HandleExceptionAsync(ErrorContext errorContext, Func<ErrorContext, Task> next)
    {
        var headers = errorContext.HttpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders();
        var acceptHeader = headers.Accept;

        if (acceptHeader?.Any(h => h.IsSubsetOf(_jsonMediaType)) == true)
        {
            errorContext.HttpContext.Items.Add(ErrorContextItemsKey, errorContext);
            await _respondWithProblemDetails(errorContext.HttpContext);
        }
        else
        {
            await next(errorContext);
        }
    }
}

internal class ErrorProblemDetailsResult : IResult
{
    private readonly Exception _ex;

    public ErrorProblemDetailsResult(Exception ex)
    {
        _ex = ex;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
        {
            Title = $"An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request",
            Detail = $"{_ex.GetType().Name}: {_ex.Message}",
            Status = _ex switch
            {
                BadHttpRequestException ex => ex.StatusCode,
                _ => StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError
            }
        };
        problemDetails.Extensions.Add("exception", _ex.GetType().FullName);
        problemDetails.Extensions.Add("stack", _ex.StackTrace);
        problemDetails.Extensions.Add("headers", httpContext.Request.Headers.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => (string)kvp.Value));
        problemDetails.Extensions.Add("routeValues", httpContext.GetRouteData().Values);
        problemDetails.Extensions.Add("query", httpContext.Request.Query);
        var endpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
        if (endpoint != null)
        {
            var routeEndpoint = endpoint as RouteEndpoint;
            var httpMethods = endpoint?.Metadata.GetMetadata<IHttpMethodMetadata>()?.HttpMethods;
            problemDetails.Extensions.Add("endpoint", new {
                endpoint?.DisplayName,
                routePattern = routeEndpoint?.RoutePattern.RawText,
                routeOrder = routeEndpoint?.Order,
                httpMethods = httpMethods != null ? string.Join(", ", httpMethods) : ""
            });
        }

        var result = Results.Json(problemDetails, statusCode: problemDetails.Status, contentType: "application/problem+json");

        await result.ExecuteAsync(httpContext);
    }
}

public static class ProblemDetailsDeveloperPageExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a <see cref="IDeveloperPageExceptionFilter"/> that formats all exceptions as JSON Problem Details to clients
    /// that indicate they support JSON via the Accepts header.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">The <see cref="IServiceCollection"/></param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="IServiceCollection"/></returns>
    public static IServiceCollection AddProblemDetailsDeveloperPageExceptionFilter(this IServiceCollection services) =>
        services.AddSingleton<IDeveloperPageExceptionFilter, ProblemDetailsDeveloperPageExceptionFilter>();
}
```

You register it in DI like so:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddProblemDetailsDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

var app = builder.Build();
```

For the non-development scenario, you can either register your own endpoint that you want to use to handle exceptions and implement the desired behavior there, or you could use a middleware like [this one](https://github.com/khellang/Middleware#problemdetails-).

To do it yourself, you would register the exception handler middleware and point it at your error endpoint which is written to return problem details, [like this](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MinimalApiPlayground/blob/8f6c3e9573905c11ed9feabab15a049d2a732af1/src/MinimalApiPlayground/Program.cs#L42-L64):

```cs
...
var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
}

var problemJsonMediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/problem+json");
app.MapGet("/error", (HttpContext context) =>
    {
        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()?.Error;
        var badRequestEx = error as BadHttpRequestException;
        var statusCode = badRequestEx?.StatusCode ?? StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;

        if (context.Request.GetTypedHeaders().Accept?.Any(h => problemJsonMediaType.IsSubsetOf(h)) == true)
        {
            // JSON Problem Details
            return error switch
            {
                BadHttpRequestException ex => Results.Extensions.Problem(detail: ex.Message, statusCode: ex.StatusCode),
                _ => Results.Extensions.Problem()
            };
        }

        // Plain text
        context.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        return Results.Text(badRequestEx?.Message ?? "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.");
    })
   .ExcludeFromDescription();
...
```

Note that some of this example uses a [custom `IResult` implementation](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MinimalApiPlayground/blob/8f6c3e9573905c11ed9feabab15a049d2a732af1/src/MinimalApiPlayground/Properties/ResultHelpers.cs) right now due to an issue that's being fixed in the upcoming rc.2 release of ASP.NET Core 6.0

Comment: Could you provide a link to the issue in github that forced you to use a custom IResult implementation?

Comment: @damian-edwards is it OK to catch and handle a `BadHttpRequestException` in a middleware? Will it not break the ASP.Net infrastructure? I saw it being handled in https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Http/Http1MessageBody.cs#L60

Comment: @Gebb it's fine